# JavaFX вращение контрола мышью вокруг своего центра

Tags: java, javafx, математика, геометрия

Собственно, весь вопрос поставлен в заголовке. Однако, при вращении обнаружены некоторые баги. Для начала алгоритм вращения:

- Вычисляем точку щелчка мышки по контролу
- Перемещаем мышь и вычисляем вторую точку мышки
- Строим два вектора из полученных выше точек в центр контрола
- Применяем скалярное произведение, тем самым получая угол поворота
- Строим еще один вектор из новых координат мыши в старые
- Применяем векторное произведение на полученный вектор и первый вектор, тем самым получая направление вращения
- Поворачиваем (setRotate)
- Заменяем старые координаты мыши на новые

Вращаю я Pane. Но, это совсем не важно. Артефакты я отобразил на видео ниже. Как видно, при большом радиусе между центром и положением мыши всё хорошо, но чем меньше радиус - тем больше вылезает артефактов. Как побороть? Спасибо.

[youtube.com](https://youtu.be/OyqihJGDRDQ)

Как видно, в первом случае вращение отрабатывает правильно,
во - втором случае на 270 - 360 градусах происходит убыстрение вращения, 
а в - третьем случае вращение доходит лишь до ~230 градусов.
И напоследок - код:

```
private double oldX;
private double oldY;
private double a = 0;
// ........

setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
            Bounds bbox = localToScene(getBoundsInParent());
            centerX = (bbox.getMinX() + bbox.getWidth()) / 2;
            centerY = (bbox.getMinY() + bbox.getHeight()) / 2;

            oldX = e.getSceneX();
            oldY = e.getSceneY();
        }
    });
    setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
            double _x = e.getSceneX();
            double _y = e.getSceneY();

            // получаем угол между векторами
            Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(oldX - centerX, oldY - centerY);
            Vector2 v2 = new Vector2(_x - centerX, _y - centerY);
            double angle = v1.degreeAngleForVectors((v2));
            // получаем направление поворота
            Vector2 v3 = new Vector2(_x - oldX, _y - oldY);
            double z = v1.cross(v3);
            // меняем градусы в зависимости от направления поворота
            angle = z >= 0 ? angle : -angle;

            oldX = _x;
            oldY = _y;

            a += angle;
            // поворачиваем контрол
            setRotate(a);
        }
    });
```

Класс вектор:

```
public class Vector2 extends Vector {

public Vector2(double x, double y){
    super(x, y);
}

public Vector2(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2){
    super(x2-x1, y2-y1);
}

@Override
public double scalar(Vector v) {
    return x * v.x + y * v.y;
}

@Override
public double length() {
    return Math.abs(Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y)));
}

@Override
public double degreeAngleForVectors(Vector v) {
    double scalar = scalar(v);
    double length = length() * v.length();
    double result = scalar / length;
    return (Math.acos(result) * 180.) / Math.PI;
}

@Override
public double cross(Vector v) {
    return x*v.y - v.x * y;
}
```

}

**UPD1:**
Сделал способом, который посоветовал *Serhii Dikobrazko*:

```
public class TestControl extends Pane {
    private double a;
    private double centerX;
    private double centerY;
    private double angleStart;
    private double angleStartPane;

    public TestControl(){
       super();
       a = 0;
       angleStart = 0;

    // events
    setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
            Bounds bbox = localToScene(getBoundsInParent());
            centerX = (bbox.getMinX() + bbox.getWidth()) / 2;
            centerY = (bbox.getMinY() + bbox.getHeight()) / 2;

            oldX = e.getSceneX();
            oldY = e.getSceneY();

            angleStart = Math.atan((oldY - centerY) / (oldX - centerX));
            angleStartPane = getRotate();
        }
    });
    setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
            double _x = e.getSceneX();
            double _y = e.getSceneY();

            double angleCurrent = Math.atan((_y - centerY) / (_x - centerX));
            double angleFinal = angleCurrent - angleStart + angleStartPane;
            a += angleFinal;
            System.out.println(a);
            setRotate(a);

        }
    });
   }
}
```

Результат: [youtube.com](https://youtu.be/876HMLQX2YE)
Как видно, при вращении по часовой вновь ошибки. когда завершается поворот(почти полные 360), а в обратную сторону проблемы ещё более серьёзные.
P.S.: JavaFX угол не запоминает, поэтому я его "накапливаю" в поле *a*.

**UPD 2:**
[youtube.com](https://youtu.be/3zI8rpv0F_c)
Результат сильно похож на изначальную проблему, если не полностью её повторяет.

Comment: А вектора тут принципиально нужны? Просто и без них тут все довольно банальнорешается

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko Буду рад любому решению:)

Comment: Но зачем накапливать угол в переменной? И что же происходит если просто присвоить значение панели?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, был не внимателен, метод setRotate принимает градусы. Переделал. И всё почти идеально, кроме одного. Сейчас обновлю пост.

Comment: крайне странное поведение. Только дебажить и смотреть где угол неправильно считает

Comment: https://pastebin.com/q95CMy3y смотри

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko прекрасно! Спасибо, всё отлично работает. Ошибка была в формуле, я не до конца её дописал..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без векторов. Ошибку искать трудно
Готовое решение не дам, но алгоритм покажу

```
Point center; // координаты центра панели в родительском узле
Point cursor; // координаты курсора в родительском узле
```

Теперь когда правой кнопкой мыши зажимаем и тянем, срабатывает наше событие для поворота.

При **первом** вызове необходимо запомнить угол наклона отрезка от центра панели, до курсора. Найти угол по двум точкам просто. Не помню точно, вроде бы (x1 - x2)/(y1 - y2).
И еще угол поворота самой панели

```
float cursorStartAngle;  // стартовый 
float paneStartAngle = pane.getRotate();
```

Он понадобится чтобы потом сделать смещение. Это как бы стартовое значение угла

Теперь при каждом следующем перемещении нужно считать этот же угол и записывать его в другую переменную

```
float cursorAngle; // угол по направлению к курсору
```

А теперь панель нужно повернуть на разницу между углом что есть сейчас и углом, что был изначально при срабатывании события драга правой кнопкой мыши 
float rotateAngle = cursorAngle - cursorStartAngle;
Я не знаю как в javaFx поворот работает, но если он не плюсуется, то при каждом присвоении будет сбрасываться в ноль

```
float rotateAngle = cursorAngle - cursorStartAngle + paneStartAngle;
```

И уже его присвоить нужной панели.

Comment: Чуть поправил. Такой алгоритм должен работать с событием onMouseDraged

Comment: Обновил свой пост, использовал Ваш метод. Там всё описал.